# Can I use a 4.7uf 50v in place of a 4.7uf 25v?

Tags: capacitor

I am rebuilding an audio regulator board on an old school video game. Its a donkey Kong junior coin op to be exact.

My question is....will a 4.7uf 50v work in place of a 4.7uf 25v?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a higher voltage rating when replacing capacitors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/291856/can-i-use-a-higher-voltage-rating-when-replacing-capacitors)

Answer (score 9):

Probably yes: Ideally you should replace the capacitor with one of the same nominal capacitance and an equal or greater maximum voltage rating.

Unless otherwise marked, for electrolytic capacitors (likely the type you are using) the tolerance of the capacitance is usually -20% to +80% of the nominal rating.  That means the capacitor you are replacing (nominally 4.7 uF of capacitance) had an actual capacitance between 3.8 uF and 8.5 uF.  Unless you have analyzed the circuit to determine what the capacitor does, it is usually best to substitute one with the same "nameplate" capacitance.  For applications like filtering capacitors in a power supply or decoupling capacitors next to a digital IC, it is usually ok to use a greater capacitance.

The voltage rating of the capacitor indicates the maximum voltage it can withstand without damage.  You can always substitute a capacitor with a higher voltage rating into a circuit designed to use a capacitor with a lower rating.

One more thing to keep in mind: There are other specifications that may be important for this application, too.  Things like equivalent series resistance (ESR) can affect performance in higher-frequency circuits.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Just don't go below 25v. The 4.7uF is an "exact" value, whereas the 25v is a *maximum* rating.